# Save entered content into a HTML page on Android to storage

Tags: java, android, save

I'm currently developing an application which allows the users to enter details into certain fields. Once the users presses save I want this content to be saved together into a .html file where  is chosen by the user. This file will be saved into the users storage in which the user can access and transfer it how ever they like.

I've searched StackOverflow on previous questions of this type but can't seem to find any. The problem I need help with is how to create and save the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like saving normal txt file instead of using `file.txt` use `file.html`. That should be work.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `PrintWriter`:

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {
    //get your fields
    //For the example:
    //String htmlChoosedFromUser  = myEditText1.getText().toString(),
    //       titleChoosedFromUser = myEditText2.getText().toString(),
    //       bodyChoosedFromUser  = myEditText3.getText().toString();

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File(htmlChoosedFromUser+".html")));
    pw.print(String.format("<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>%s</body>"),titleChoosedFromUser,bodyChoosedFromUser);
    pw.close();
}
});
```